# Use an ACF shortcode value that returns a url as the src for an image tag

Tags: html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, broken-image

Trying to create an image that can be reused multiple times on different pages throughout the site through it's url. Currently using ACF to create an image field on a page where the file is located, from there using an ACF shortcode placed in the scr="" to output the image.

Without the img tag just using the shortcode **`[acf field="name" post_id="24"]`** it returns

`http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/iain-e1593698192670.jpg`

Following this link provides the image in a new tab so I figure the url isn't the source of the problem.

The current set up is

```
<img src="[acf field="iain" post_id="24"]">
```

The result: **the annoying broken image icon**.

**EDIT**

Using Beaver Builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot nest double quotes inside double quotes like you had them - you can either use single quotes around the shortcode, or use them for the attributes inside the shortcode.

**If you are using the shortcode in a template**, you need to use the [`do_shortcode` PHP function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/). Otherwise it just displays the actual shortcode text on the page. In your case, it is looking for an image with a url `[acf field="iain" post_id="24"]`, which is why you're getting a broken image.

You need to change the image source to the following:

```
<img src="<?php echo do_shortcode('[acf field="iain" post_id="24"]'); ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was to do with double nesting the quotes. The resultant code that worked looked like this `<img src="[acf field='iain' post_id='24']">`.

Answer (score 0):

FluffyKitten is right, but I recomend not to use shortcode in that way as you do.
Is even preferable to make a dedicated shortcode and use it, like this:

```
// Shortcode dedicated to print the main image
add_shortcode("print_main_img","print_main_img_f");

function print_main_img_f($atts , $content = null, $tag = ''){
    // Taking params
    $structdata = shortcode_atts( array('id' => 24), $atts, $tag);
    
    // Putting each in a variable
    $imgid = esc_html__($structdata['id'], 24);

    $img_url = get_field("iain",$imgid);
    
    if(!empty($img_url)){
        return '<img src="'.$img_url.'" />';
    }
    else{
        return 'Invalid ID';
    }
}
```

You can use it like this
[print_main_img] and it will take by default id 24 or like this
[print_main_img id=55] and it will take id 55.